# Backbone js show only one element of each list in html

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, espocrm

I am primarily sorry for my English. Backbone js each list I want to select and display only one value in the loop. How can I do that ? I will show you sample codes.If there's a place you do not understand, ask.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Backbone JS code;**

```
    _template: '<div class="list-container">{{{list}}}</div>',


    defaultListLayout: {
        rows: [
            [
                {
                    name: 'entityType'
                },
                {
                    name: 'calculationType'
                },
                {
                    name: 'calculationValue'
                },
                {
                    name: 'queryType'
                }
            ]
        ]
    },

    afterRender: function () {
        this.collection = new MultiCollection();
        this.collection.seeds = this.seeds;
        this.collection.url = 'CareerSteps/action/careerGoal';
        this.collection.maxSize =         this.getConfig().get('recordsPerPageSmall') || 5;
        this.collection.data.entityTypeList = this.scopeList;            
        this.listenToOnce(this.collection, 'sync', function () {
            this.createView('list',         'career:views/dashlets/templates/newtemplate', {
                el: this.options.el + ' > .list-container',
                pagination: false,
                type: 'list',                    
                checkboxes: false,
                collection: this.collection,
                listLayout: this.listLayout,
            }, function (view) {
                view.render();
            });
        }, this);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },
```

**HTML Code;**

```
<ul class="list-group">          
    {{#each rowList}}
        <li data-id="{{./this}}" class="list-group-item list-row">        
          {{{var this ../this}}} <br>        
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: You have an array inside an array `rows: [
            [`... so you'll need 2 loops. But you only seem to have one. Or is this a mistake?

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem. I solved.